# i18next module does not compile within React-Typescript application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next, tsdx

I have a **React-Typescript** application and had recently configured **i18next** setup for multi-language support. I believe all of the setups have been done correctly by following the guidelines of the official documentation. However, when I run the app, it gives me a bunch of compilation errors, such as;

```
Property 'changeLanguage' does not exist on type 'typeof import("...some_path_info.../node_modules/i18next/index")'.
```

or

```
Module '"i18next"' has no exported member 'Module'
```

I tried a bunch of different `tsconfig.json` configurations, such as including the type definition file from the `node_modules` folder of **i18next**, and other things, but none of them solved the issue, here is the current version of my `tsconfig.json` file;

```
"include": ["src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2019",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
    "importHelpers": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "baseUrl": "." /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */,
    "paths": {
      "libdefs/*": ["src/libdefs/*"]
    },
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

After spending lots of time searching and testing, I found a way to make it work, and can lead me to the real solution, however, I still couldn't figure it out. The thing is, when I go to the `node_modules` folder of the **i18next**, the default file structure looks like this;

[image: Default File Structure of i18next package]

Within this package, when I tried to move the `index.d.ts` type definition file inside the `dist` folder and then build my project, everything started to work magically without any further configuration or change. However, obviously, it is not a permanent solution.

Finally, I need a permanent solution to this problem, and my last finding about manipulating the package folder of **i18next** can give some hints.

Here are the versions for related packages;

```
"i18next": "^22.0.6",
"react-i18next": "^12.0.0",
```

Thanks.

Comment: As per the error states “node_modules/i18next/“index”, can you confirm that your imports on that page are correctly set as per the [documentation here](https://react.i18next.com/getting-started#basic-sample) like below; `import i18n from "i18next";
import { useTranslation, initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";`

Comment: using i18next in combination with i18next, you may have a look at: https://www.i18next.com/overview/typescript https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react-typescript/simple

Comment: can you verify using a compatible nodejs version.

Answer (score -1):

I think the package that you used is not using in React.js that is for Next.js. I suggest using `React-intl` package for supporting multi language in react applications.
[React-intl documentation](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/)

and also have a look on this blog which done localization using react-intl [React i18n: A step-by-step guide to React-intl](https://lokalise.com/blog/react-i18n-intl/)